# combine result of 2 queries into 1 with same group by

Tags: sql, join, union

`enter code here`I have 2 queries that use 2 tables, orders and users:

```
--Q1           

SELECT city , AVG(number_of_food_orders_last_month)
FROM (
  SELECT o.city,o.user_id, count(*) AS number_of_food_orders_last_month
  FROM orders AS o
  where bla..bla..                                
  GROUP BY o.city,o.user_id 
)                                                                          
GROUP BY city      
ORDER BY city  
                                                      
--Q2

SELECT o.city, count(distinct u.id) 
FROM users as u 
INNER JOIN orders AS o 
ON o.user_id=u.id
WHERE bla bla IN (
          SELECT id
          FROM users 
          WHERE bla..bla            
)                                                        
GROUP BY o.city
ORDER BY o.city
```

They are grouped by the city of the orders table so I want to output the result of the 2 queries in one result table. How do I do it? I tried UNION but it doesn't work. Maybe I did it wrong.

```
Example:
Q1 outputs:
city    avg
Madrid   1.00
Malaga   2.00
Murcia   1.00
Valencia 3.00

         
Q2 outputs:
 city    count
Madrid   6
Malaga   4
Murcia   10
Valencia 8
            
I want:
 city    count  avg
Madrid   6      1.0
Malaga   4      2.0
Murcia   10     1.0
Valencia 8      3.0
```

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Sample data and desired results would really help.  "Combine" is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should join them:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
--Q1           

SELECT city AS cityQ1 , AVG(number_of_food_orders_last_month) as average_number_of_food_orders_last_month
FROM (
  SELECT o.city,o.user_id, count(*) AS number_of_food_orders_last_month
  FROM orders AS o
  where bla..bla..                                
  GROUP BY o.city,o.user_id 
)     AS average_number_of_food_orders_by_user_last_month                                                                     
GROUP BY city      
ORDER BY city  
) Q1 
INNER JOIN 
(
--Q2

SELECT o.city as cityQ2, count(distinct u.id) as count_users
FROM users as u 
INNER JOIN orders AS o 
ON o.user_id=u.id
WHERE bla bla IN (
          SELECT id
          FROM users 
          WHERE bla..bla            
)                                                        
GROUP BY o.city
ORDER BY o.city
) Q2 ON Q1.cityQ1 = Q2.cityQ2
```

if you can add the city ids to Q1 and Q2 it will better for the join instead of the city names.

Comment: if I need to add multiple queries do I do: 

  `select * (
    FROM (
    Q1
    ) q1 
    INNER JOIN (
    Q2) q2 
    ON q1.city1=q2.city2 
    INNER JOIN (
    Q3) q3 
    ON q1.cityq1=q2.cityq2 AND q2.cityq2=q3.cityq3`

 etc?

Comment: I did a very big query with 4 inner joins and I got funny results

I got this type of result from my massive SQL query with 4 INNER JOINS:

     `city        city_group   col1   col2   col3    col4
    Barcelona  Group1   4  
    Girona      Group4     0   1   1.00 
    Madrid      Group2                  
    Malaga                                   3
    Murcia      Group3                      2.00    6
    Valencia  Group3    1     3
                                8

                                      0        5.00`

Comment: Basically instead of all result columns having 6 rows I got total 12 rows.. so there is something that doesn't work properly..
Does it have to be an INNER JOIN or OUTER JOIN?

Comment: It is really depend on the tables you use. for example on the query above if the tables and the FK are good you can do it as one query that calculate the count and average at the same time. but for this you will need to add the tables schema.